# HTML Links within Bootstrap collapse not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink

I am pretty new with JS and therefore believe the problem comes from this part.

The links that are being toggled/collapsed with the bootstrap JS don't "work" properly : when clicking on them, the page isn't followed. However, when right-clicking and opening in a new tab/window no problem. Ctrl-click also doesn't work.

Here the second link works but not the first one.

Here is the html :

```
<a class = "carre" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#link"></a>
<div data-toggle = "collapse" class ="panel-collapse collapse" id = "link">
<a href = "http://www.google.com" >link</a>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<a href = "http://www.google.com" >link</a>
```

And CSS :

```
.carre{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    margin-bottom:15px:
}
```

Here is the link to an example JSFiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/t7mpv6vk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here i got solution for your problem:

Check updated Fiddle here: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ketan156/t7mpv6vk/2/)

Write `onClick="event.stopPropagation();"` in div.

like:  `<div data-toggle = "collapse" class ="panel-collapse collapse" id = "link">`

Because When your click on link. div will get the click event instead of link.

Comment: This works great, thanks. Would you mind explaining with a bit more details how this works ?

Comment: As i explain in answer anchor tag is inside Div So,  when you click on link then div tag get the click event. on event.stopPropagation() of div click it will prevents the event from bubbling up.